# How do I train tesseract but not create a new language?

Tags: tesseract

So I am trying out tesseract at the moment, and it does work, but it is not accurate enough. I know that the image quality plays a role as well, etc. etc., but some of the documents I am using use a rather unusual font. It still does recognise parts of it though (about 50-60%, which is pretty good), but this is obviously not entirely satisfying.

I would like to know now whether it's possible to train tesseract, but not to create an entirely new language, but to use the data I am already using, and build on this and improve it?

Second, if this is possible, would this even be advisable? Or (2) would it be better to create new languages for every new font I encounter, *or* (3) create new languages for each new font I encounter, but not from scratch but always built upon the default data I am using right now? What do you think? If you can provide any links on how to train tesseract & make use of the training data already provided, do let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the files from .traineddata file as given in documentation :
specify option -u to unpack all the components to the specified path:

combine_tessdata -u tessdata/eng.traineddata /home/$USER/temp/eng.
This will create /home/$USER/temp/eng.* files with individual tessdata components from tessdata/eng.traineddata.
There are other options too,please check the documentation on the following link.
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/combine_tessdata.1.asc

But rather than playing with original files its advisable to train tesseract for a new language.

(2)You dont have to create new language for each font.You have to create image,box and training file for each font .All of these will then be combined into a single language's traineddata file.

(3)This is possible too.PLease visit
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-3.00%E2%80%933.02#bootstrapping-a-new-character-set